# NGINX not finding static files in Dockered Django project

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I'm new to using Docker and Nginx. I'm taking a project I have working locally which includes flatpages and a couple of simple apps and combining it with [this guide to utilise Docker, NGINX and Gunicorn](https://pawamoy.github.io/2018/02/01/docker-compose-django-postgres-nginx.html).

For some reason, it can't find my Static files or even the standard Django  admin static files.

**Console error**

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/flatpages/CSS/flatpages.css 
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**Django Admin**
[Django Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMErm.png)

**local.conf**

```
upstream hello_server {
    server djangoapp:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /opt/services/djangoapp/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /opt/services/djangoapp/media/;
    }
}
```

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), 
    "static"),
    '/static/flatpages/',
]
```

Amongst many other things, so far I've tried:

- Using STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS

  - My understanding from the Django docs is that with static files in
    multiple locations I need to use STATICFILES_DIRS
  - If I use STATIC_ROOT and collect static the Django Admin does find 
    the static files but won't find any others.
- Navigating the apps Docker container to find the files manually. I 
  can't locate them or any of the templates that do work. I find this 
  very odd.

Please let me know if I need to clarify or include anything else. Thanks in advance for any help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: You still need to proxy pass it to the django server

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand, you need to sync the static volume between NGINX and Django folder. For that you need to update your docker compose like this:

```
version: '3'

services:

  djangoapp:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
    networks: 
      - nginx_network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static:/opt/services/djangoapp/static/  # Syncing your current static directory to the Docker
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
    networks: 
      - nginx_network

networks: 
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Hi Ruddra, thanks for commenting. I've tried changing the docker-compose file to match your suggestion but it's still not working.

Comment: can you please access the shell of `nginx` and go to directory `/opt/services/djangoapp/static/` and type `ls` to see if there is anything exists in that directory or not?

Comment: Just an admin directory with the static files for Django. I've run collectstatic in the Django container but doesn't look like its finding the static files of my app.

Comment: Does it mean, the admin site has css now?

Comment: Yes, I got the admin static files working by setting static root to:
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), 'static')


My understanding is to pick up static files in multiple apps I need to use STATICFILES_DIRS which when I try and collectstatic it gives me this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/services/djangoapp/static'

Comment: If i understood correctly, then At least its safe to assume you're nginx and docker compose issues has been resolved. Now the problem is with static directory. It would be great if you could ask a new question regarding this, coz i can't understand what is the exact problem from comments. Also add you Dockerfile with that question.

Answer (score 1):

first if you ar using nginx lika a proxy to serve static files You, must be load the page in port 80 and you must show how run the container, nut in my cases if i pass static directory like a volume (container_path/static), you onli need set location to container_path because nginx will searc an static directory in the path set, something like this:

```
location /static/ {
        root /opt/services/djangoapp;
    }
```

and remember run collectstatic command to collect the statics files to static directory

Comment: Hi Juancarlos. Unfortunately, your suggestion isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming on your docker container the static folder is in /opt/services/djangoapp, then your location /static config should still proxy pass to the django server:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /opt/services/djangoapp/static/;

    proxy_pass http://hello_server;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect default;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. 

I've tried adding your suggested settings to location /static/ {...}. Still not working, unfortunately. 

My understanding is that the location /static/ settings extend the settings from the from the location / settings set earlier in the local.conf file. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

First, `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_ip:8000 www.your_ip:8000;

    root /var/www/html;

     location / {
             proxy_pass http://your_ip:8000;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
             proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    }

    location /static/admin {
             alias  /path/to/static/admin/;
}
    location /static/ {
             alias  /path/to/static/;
}


   location /media/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /path/to/media/; 
     }    
}
```

In settings.py STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')

then run collectstatic command

copy admin folder from static_root folder and paste it into static folder

Finally, run `service nginx restart`

Answer (score 0):

Your static file should be on same directory as your folder according to your BASE_DIR variable, check were collectstatic puts the "static" sir on your server and configure nginx to locate it.