# django 502 while deployment

Tags: django, nginx, deployment

I was trying to deploy a Django web app to Digital Ocean following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/cfa565b879ff1458dba08f423cb01d71). It is written based on a [tutorial from digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) themselves. Everything seem to be working perfectly fine until it's time to setup Nginx.

I follow it exactly every time and it always sends me a 502 Bad Gateway message.

Comment: You need to post your config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_droplet_ip:8000 www.your_droplet_ip:8000;

    root /var/www/html;

     location / {
             proxy_pass http://your_droplet_ip:8000;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
             proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

              }
     }
```

try this and after run `service nginx restart`

Comment: Hey @coderasha this kind of worked because now I can at least see welcome to nginx, but shouldn't my website be there instead of their welcome page?

Comment: Did you run `python3 manage.py runserver your_droplet_ip:8000` in your terminal?

Comment: It worked! I don't know why but I followed the exact same steps again and it worked out this time.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Additional information: After you change debug=True to debug=False Django will not serve static and media files, so instead Nginx will serve these files check my comment here and follow steps: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054261/nginx-not-finding-static-files-in-dockered-django-project/55087554#55087554]